# Is there a "not" equivalent in rspec, for e.g. the logical not for "and_return"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

Couldn't find the method in the rspec docs, but is there an alternative to do this?

```
allow_any_instance_of(<some connection>).to receive(<post method>).and_return(200)
```

the above code block to **not** return 200 instead

Answer (score 1):

You have fundamentally misunderstood what `allow_any_instance_of` and `to_return` do.

[`allow_any_instance_of`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-8/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance) is used to stub a method on any instance of a given class. It does not set any expectations - `expect_any_instance_of` does.

```
class Foo
  def bar(*args)
    "baz"
  end
end

RSpec.describe Foo do
  describe "allow_any_instance_of" do
    it "does not create an expectation" do
      allow_any_instance_of(Foo).to receive(:bar).and_call_original
      expect(true).to be_truthy
    end
  end
  describe "expect_any_instance_of" do
    it "sets an expectation" do
      expect_any_instance_of(Foo).to receive(:bar).and_call_original
      expect(Foo.new.bar).to eq 'baz'
    end
    # this example will fail
    it "fails if expected call is not sent" do
      expect_any_instance_of(Foo).to receive(:bar).and_call_original
      expect(true).to be_truthy
    end
  end
end
```

`.and_return` is used to set the return value of a mock/stub. It does not as you seem to believe set an expectation on the return value.

```
RSpec.describe Foo do
  describe "and_return" do
    it "changes the return value" do
      allow_any_instance_of(Foo).to receive(:bar).and_return('hello world')
      expect(Foo.new.bar).to_not eq 'baz'
      expect(Foo.new.bar).to eq 'hello world'
    end
  end
end
```

You can use `.and_call_original` when you want to spy on a method without changing its return value. By default any method stubbed with `allow_any_instance_of/expect_any_instance` will return nil.

AFAIK its not possible to set an expectation on what the return value of `.and_call_original` is. Thats one of reasons why `any_instance_of` is considered a code smell and should be avoided.